# How to disable Chrome Google Search Popup

Tags: google-chrome, search

When no input boxes are selected in Chrome, and you press <kbd>n</kbd> followed by <kbd>o</kbd>, chrome pops up a Google Search box.

Is there a way to disable this search box?

Comment: It dosen't seem to do it in my system. Might it be an addon?

Comment: Thank you. That did it. It was vimium's 'Vomnibar'. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a way to disable that.

Comment: let me post that as an answer then. Good to see my wild guess was right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not standard behaviour for Chrome's search popup - you have an extension that does it, and you need to change the settings of the extension if possible to fix the problem